# Paginar una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Trabajo con ASP.NET MVC 5, deseo paginar una tabla creada con html, lo he intentando con jquery pero no me ha dado resultado.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://c.fzilla.com/1291523190-jpaginate.js"></script>
    <style>
        .pagination{
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .pagination li{
            float: left;
            margin: 3px;
        }
        .pagination li a{
            display: block;
            padding: 3px 5px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #44b0dd;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .pagination li a.active{
            border: 1px solid #000;
            color: #000;
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        .pagination li a.inactive{
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #777;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        } 
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#content").jPaginate();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="content" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>ProveedorId</td>
            <td>Razón Social</td>
            <td>Número documento</td>
            <td>Dirección</td>
            <td>Teléfono</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var row in ViewBag.ListarProveedor)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@row.ProveedorId</td>
                <td>@row.RazonSocial</td>
                <td>@row.NumeroDocumento</td>
                <td>@row.Direccion</td>
                <td>@row.Telefono</td>
            </tr> 
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jPaginate is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Index:69)
at Function.ready (1286136086-jquery.js:26)
at HTMLDocument.L (1286136086-jquery.js:33)
```

Ya lo resolví

Comment: hermano, llevas bastante tiempo en SOes, no crees que te falta especificar los detalles correspondientes para analizar tu pregunta? Qué error te sale? Qué has intentado? Voto por cerrarla por ser demasiado amplia, dale los límites necesarios para ayudarte a resolver :D

Comment: Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas. Por la forma en que está escrito, es difícil determinar exactamente lo que quieres preguntar. Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Comment: @fredyfx lo que he intentado es el código que muestro

Comment: Comparto la idea de @Alvaro Montoro

Comment: @PedroÁvila ese error puede ocurrir por muchos motivos, ¿qué otros errores te aparecen antes que ese? Porque esos son los que te van a decir qué es lo que está pasando exactamente

Comment: Aparte, conseguí que me funcionara tu código "sin problemas" haciendo dos cambios simples: 1) usando la versión 1.9.1 de jQuery (parece que ese jPaginate presenta incompatibilidades con la 3.1.1, aunque esto lanzaba un error diferente); y 2) asegurándome que el script de jPaginate se cargaba (inicialmente lo estaba cargando en una página con https, pero se incluye con http y por eso fallaba). Puedes ver tu código con esos cambios funcionando aquí: http://jsfiddle.net/9zwdvs17/ (asegúrate de que entras en la versión http de JSFiddle o fallará)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tienes toda la razón con la versión 3 de jquery hay conflicto aparte en el layout tenia el jquery 3 y eso también me daba problemas, voy a poner la solución que es lo que tu tambien has hecho

Comment: <script src="http://c.fzilla.com/1286136086-jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://c.fzilla.com/1291523190-jpaginate.js"></script>